# Homologously of connected components

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

How can I prove that if $\Omega$ is homologously connected $\Rightarrow$ every connected component of $\Omega$ is homologously connected?

Comment: Please include the definition of *homologously connected* and what you've tried so far in attempting to solve the problem.

Comment: An open set in the complex plane is said to be homologously connected if the index of every closed path in the set, respect a point not belonging to the set is zero, and that for every point not in the set.

Comment: Is this the precise definition you were given? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Translation: an open set $U\subset \mathbb C$ if homologously connected if for every closed path $\gamma$ in $U$ and every point $z\in \mathbb C\setminus U$, the index (winding number) of $\gamma$ with respect to $z$ is zero.